# SDL 1.3: How to render video with out displaying it?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, sdl, shader

So what I need is simple: Imagine we have no gui at all - ssh access to some linux where we gonna build and host our app. That app would generate video stream. We have some SDL app with OpenGL shader in it. All we want is to get rendering (as normally we would have in SDL window) as a char* (with size W*H*3) How to do such thing? How to make SDL render stuff not onto its gui window but into some swappable pointer?

Answer (score 3):

To be of any use, OpenGL should be hardware accelerated, so first check if your server does have a GPU that meets your requirements. If you're on a rented virtual server or some standard root server, then you very likely don't have a GPU.

If you have a GPU, then there are two possible methods:

---

**Method 1** -- the easy one

You'll (unfortunately) have to configure and start the X server for it **and** this X server must also be the current virtual terminal (i.e. it must be the active thing on the graphics card). Then you give the user who'll be running that video generator access to that X display (read `man xauth` and what it references)

The next step is independent of SDL, it's an OpenGL think: Create a Framebuffer Object onto which the desired graphics is rendered; a PBuffer would work as well, and actually I'd prefer it in this situation, however I found Framebuffer Objects be more reliable than PBuffers on current Linux and its drivers.

Then render to this Framebuffer Object or PBuffer as usual and retrieve the content using `glReadPixels`

---

**Method 2** -- the flexible one

On the low level this is quite similar to Method 1, but things get abstracted for you: Get *VirtualGL* http://www.virtualgl.org/ to perform the actual OpenGL rendering on the GPU. Instead of starting your application on a secondary X server you make direct use of the VirtualGL server provided sending the GLX stream and get a JPEG image stream back. You could also use a secondary X server running a virtual framebuffer and take a continous screencapture of that. Or probably most elegant: Write your own X.Org video driver that passes the video to the video streamer directly.

---

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly render to a byte array in OpenGL.

There are two ways to work with this. The first way is the simplest and doesn't require context gimmickery, and the second way does.

So first, the simple way.

In order for OpenGL to work, you need to have a window. That doesn't mean the window needs to be *visible*, but you need to create one to get a valid OpenGL context. Therefore **Step 1: Create a window and minimize it.**

Now, in order to get valid rendering, the pixels in the framebuffer must pass the "pixel ownership test." When rendering to the framebuffer that holds the screen itself, pixels of the window that are not actually visible on screen fail the pixel ownership test. So the values of those pixels are undefined if you use glReadPixels.

However, this only pertains to the default framebuffer that is associated with the window. Framebuffer objects *always* pass the pixel ownership test. Therefore, **Step 2: Create a framebuffer object and the associated renderbuffers for your needs.**

From there, it's pretty simple. Just render as normal and do a glReadPixels when you want to get the data. [Pixel buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) can be used to asynchronous transfer pixel data, if performance is a concern. **Step 3: Render and use glReadPixels to get the data.**

---

The second way is more widely available (FBOs require extension support or OpenGL 3.0), but more platform-specific.

Instead of creating an FBO in step 2, you instead have **Step 2: use [glXCreatePbuffer](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.opengl/doc/openglrf/glXCreatePbuffer.htm) to create a pbuffer.** A pbuffer is an off-screen render target that acts like the default framebuffer. You [glXMakeContextCurrent](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.opengl/doc/openglrf/glXMakeContextCurrent.htm) to tell OpenGL to render to the pbuffer instead of the default framebuffer.

Steps 1 and 3 are the same as above.